# Javascript if statement evaluates false, but still runs (Safari only)

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari, logic

[image: The if-statement]

This if-statement is falsy, as you can see from this screenshot from the Safari debugger. But as you also may see by the green line, it still executes as if the statement was true.

This happens only in Safari, whereas both Chrome and Firefox works as expected.

Why is this happening? Might it be that we've run into a bug of some sort?

Simplified, the if-statement is basically `if( true && (false || false))`

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var type = "first";
var subtype = "second";

if (div.dataset.type == "first" && (!div.dataset.subtype || div.dataset.subtype == subtype)) {
  div.innerText = 'Should never run'
} else div.innerText = 'Works as expected';
```

```html
<div data-type="first" data-subtype="none"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, Safari, the new Internet Explorer.

Comment: Something for hackers... ^^

Comment: Are you quite certain the line runs? My guess is it's just a glitch in the debugger's highlighting. Separately: What are you hovering to get that `false`?

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button), so we can see it for ourselves. Barring that, it's **much** more likely to be observational error than a fundamental bug in Safari's JavaScript expression evaluation. See: [`select` is not broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, it does run, not just in the debugger but also on the page itself. I'm hovering the entire expression to get the false, which basically is `if( true && (false || false))`

Comment: @pestbarn—the code in the OP returns "Works as expected" in Safari 10.1.2 (and I expect every other version).

Comment: @RobG It does for me as well. But not in the application itself.

Comment: So you're back to square one: post code that replicates the issue.

Comment: So what does `console.log(div.dataset.type, div.dataset.subtype)`return?

Comment: @RobG Sadly I'm not able to replicate it in a simple enough manner. The application itself is an unreleased one for one of our clients, so I cannot refer you to the original codebase either...

Comment: @epascarello The `console.log` returns `first` and `none`, respectively.

Comment: The string "none"?

Comment: @epascarello Yes, sorry. Both are strings, `"first"` and `"none"`

Comment: As far as I can tell, the debugger is telling you that *element.dataset.subtype* has the value `false`, it is not the result of the entire *if* expression. I can replicate the OP image only by setting *element.dataset.subtype* to false. Hover over "type" in *element.dataset.type* and it will show "first".

Comment: @RobG That's not the case either. Consider this: http://imgur.com/a/QlOCi

Comment: The first image is showing that the entire expression evaluates to false. The second is showing that the `!element.dataset.type` part is false. That is plausible, or at least not inconsistent (*cf* `!'string'`). Now comes nap time… :-)

Comment: would you mind ... add `debugger` into if-block and show us debugger is paused at there when expr is evaluated as false?

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing "**==**" to "**===**" in your **if** conditions. In javascript, comparison happens after type coercion.

Comment: I think the OP understands the abstract equality comparison algorithm.

Comment: I don't see any issue apart from that and curly braces around `div.innerText = 'Works as expected';`, so.